# Having two Android activity in foreground

Tags: android

When calling someone with messenger on android the app open an other activity in foreground and we can switch between each other like if they were two different apps.
Could someone give me some information on how this works?
This seems impossible for me based on what I know about android.

Comment: It is possible beacuse of Android services for example. Read more about it here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=es-419

Comment: Could you please supply more details, the provided details are not sufficient to suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing over other apps would be a way to implement this.

[here you have a simple example of it.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-draw-over-other-apps-in-android/)